# Can't get input type="text" value in action on form submit?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In a Razor view I have `input type="text"`, a hidden field and a button. I can access hidden field from Form collection but its weird I cant access `input type="text"` value inside my action. I am not sure if my understanding is correct or not but I was thinking as all fields inside form should be available inside action.

Below is my code please:

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
    <div style="margin-top: 40px;">
    <input id="txtDateFrom" class="span2" size="16" value="@Model.StartDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") " readonly="readonly" type="text">
    @Html.Hidden("currencyCode", (object)ViewBag.currencyCode)
    </div>
    <button onclick="@Url.Action("ExchangeRateDetails", "ExchangeRate")" class="btn btn-lg     span2 ARML50px">
    }
```

I highly appreciate your time, guidance and help.

Comment: Down vote ? gentleman can you please guide why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your hidden input works is that you render this with help from the Html helper @Html.Hidden. This helper render the input field with the name attribute.

Your `<input type="text">` is missing the name attribute. So try writing like this:

```
<input id="txtDateFrom" name="txtDateFrom" class="span2" size="16" value="@Model.StartDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") " readonly="readonly" type="text" />
```

The name="txtDateFrom" will make the value appear in your FormCollection.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

You don't need `onclick="@Url.Action("ExchangeRateDetails", "ExchangeRate")"` to the button

Change your button for below way

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg span2 ARML50px">
```

And Now your controller can get the input text

```
[HttpPost]
Public ActionResult ExchangeRateDetails(YourmodelClass xxx)
{
 string dates=Model.StartDate;
}
```

> This website have lot and lot of answers for [how to send a model values from view to controllers](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=foo&oq=foo&aqs=chrome..69i57l2j69i60j69i59j69i60l2.778j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=93&espv=210&q=how%20to%20send%20a%20model%20values%20from%20view%20to%20controllers%20in%20mvc%20) by see the Related discussion on this page right corner .

Comment: thanks, this looks a good approach but unfortunately it is not working here. On action I am able to get viewmodel object but its StartDate has value model.StartDate = {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM} which is wrong. Can you please through further light on this approach ? Thanks